# Javascript check >= 0 not null or undefined or ''

Tags: javascript

What is the most convenient / performant way to check if a variable is greater than or equal to 0 **and** not `null` or `undefined` or `''`? e.g. `[0, Infinity)`. Let's say my variable is `x`, the obvious `x >= 0` doesn't work as `null >= 0` is `true`. The best I could come up with was.

```
x > 0 || x === 0
```

Can anyone think of a better one?

It seems like this question should already exist so if someone can find this question I'm happy to delete mine.

Comment: `x && x >= 0` i think :). First checks for null, if not then it checks if its greater or equal

Comment: Maybe `parseFloat(x) >= 0` (would work when `x` is a string though)

Comment: If `x=null` then `x && x >= 0` evaluates to `null`.  I'm not really sure that helps? Or `x=""` then `x && x >= 0` evaluates to `""`

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not the answer you're looking for but why not check for number first?

```
if (typeof x === "number" && x >= 0) {
  // Excludes non-number values such as null and undefined
}
```

Note that this will allow `Infinity`, if you want finite numbers only:

```
if (typeof x === "number" && isFinite(x) && x >= 0) {
  // ...
}
```

The number type check clarifies your *intent*.

Any attempt to make it short and smart will most likely rely on type coercion which is risky, complicated (not everybody is familiar with JS quirks) and unnecessary from a performance point of view.

Comment: I like the thinking behind this, I'll accept if nothing better comes in. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (x != null && x >= 0)
{
    //then insert the code to be executed here
}
```

Comment: it stops directly on zero.

Answer (score 0):

The not null call could be as follows

```
value !== null
```

And i think you should just keep the above zero check your already doing!

Answer (score -1):

You can just check if the variable has a truthy value or not. That means

if( value ) {
}
will evaluate to true if value is not:

null
undefined
NaN
empty string ("")
0
false
The above list represents all possible falsy values in ECMA-/Javascript. Find it in the specification at the ToBoolean section.

Further read: http://typeofnan.blogspot.com/2011/01/typeof-is-fast.html

Comment: But I want it to pass on 0 also `if(value)` fails on 0

Answer (score -1):

Use non-strict comparison with `null` and then compare numbers:

```js
function check(x) {
  return x != null && 0 <= x;
}

console.log(check(1), true);
console.log(check(0), true);
console.log(check(-1), false);
console.log(check(null), false);
console.log(check(undefined), false);

console.log(check('1'), true);
console.log(check('0'), true);
console.log(check('Hello'), false);
console.log(check('-1 and 2 and 3'), false);
```

Comment: @GlenThompson You have never specified empty sting as possible value. Then add simply `x != ''` to expression

Comment: Its in the question title, I'll add it to the body though.